# SVN commit to source url

Tags: svn, branch, commit

I'm new to SVN. Sorry if this is stupid.

I checked out a branch from branches/features_jira_392 and named the local folder 'john_features_jira_392'. I made some edits. When I committed it through Tortoise SVN it created a new branch called 'branches/john_features_jira_392'.

This was **not** what I was expecting. I thought it would commit to the source URL (without the prefix john) from which I checked out the branch. Can I not change the name locally or how do I keep the source URl as the destination URL for commit?

Comment: In what way did you change the folder name? You *ought to* have used the checkout dialog, or just renamed the folder with normal windows commands after the checkout, in which case TSVN would have done exactly what you wanted. So how did you change it?

Comment: obviously I user errored it. I renamed it after I checked it out with normal window commands.It would seem that this was the no no. Renaming the folder with the checkout dialog worked fine.

Comment: SVN won't automatically rename anything for you, if you use normal Windows commands. However if you used the "rename" command from the TortoiseSVN menu, then you'll get the server-side rename you're indicating. There may be a few other ways to get it to happen, but they all require manual steps.